# Nonblocking bash commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

So I just created the .bash_aliases and wrote the following:

```
callNotepad(){
     wine C:\\Program\ Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe $1
}

alias notepad++=callNotepad
```

Now whether notepad++ is already running or not, if it is not it does open notepad++ and either way, it opens whatever file I specify when I call

```
notepad++ someFile
```

However, if notepad++ was not running prior to that command, it gives me a

> fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid
>   {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}

and then blocks the calling terminal for as long as notepad is running.

How would I implement that alias correctly?
For I have no idea what that fixme is supposed to tell me.

Also, I would prefer not having to open a second terminal after opening a file in notepad++ (ctrl+C reenables the terminal but closes notepad++).

Comment: Couldn't you just do `callNotepad(){
     wine C:\\Program\ Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe $1 &
}

alias notepad++=callNotepad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command [in the background](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists).

```
callNotepad(){
     wine 'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' "$1" &
}
```

If you want to silence the errors, [redirect them](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output) into silence.

```
callNotepad(){
     wine 'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' "$1" 2>/dev/null &
}
```

Note that this may also silence useful errors, so use at your own risk.

Comment: Still gives me the errors but now it does not close notepad anymore when Ctrl+C out of them. Thank you.

Comment: The *"errors"* are because Wine, nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @User1291 The error is due to Wine not being a perfect emulation of Windows. You can't do anything about it. You can silence the errors (see my edit) but this may cause you to miss useful error messages.

Comment: I don't really feel like taking the risk of missing something that I actually should worry about so I'll just ctrl+c and clear. Thanks for clearing that up, though.

Comment: if you want to avoid using wine: use geany instead of notepad++ (they are almost identical)